# Select records where ID from one table is present in one or more other tables

Tags: mysql, select, join, inner-join

OK, so I've found questions that cover how to do this with only two tables, tons of questions that explain how to do this if the ID does NOT exist in other tables, but not a solution to this query.

Basically, I have one table of wine vintages.

I then have four other tables that contain different types of content that is tied to a specific vintage (i.e. videos, blogs etc.)

I basically need to be able to pull a list of vintages that are in use i.e. where the vintage ID is used in one or more of the four content tables.

The closest I can get is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vintage_id FROM `pr_video_vintage`
INNER JOIN pr_video ON pr_video.fk_vintage_id = pr_video_vintage.vintage_id
INNER JOIN pr_reports ON pr_reports.fk_vintage_id = pr_video_vintage.vintage_id
INNER JOIN pr_reports_notes ON pr_reports_notes.fk_vintage_id = pr_video_vintage.vintage_id
INNER JOIN pr_blog_entries ON pr_blog_entries.fk_vintage_id = pr_video_vintage.vintage_id
ORDER BY `pr_video_vintage`.`vintage_id` ASC
```

But this (understandably I guess) only returns IDs that exist in ALL of the tables.

What I need is some form of 'OR' JOIN, but can't find any information out about how to go about doing this.

tips? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  distinct vintage_id FROM `pr_video_vintage`
where exists(select 1 from pr_video where pr_video.fk_vintage_id = pr_video_vintage.vintage_id)
   or exists(select 1 from pr_reports where pr_reports.fk_vintage_id = pr_video_vintage.vintage_id)
   or exists(select 1 from pr_reports_notes where pr_reports_notes.fk_vintage_id = pr_video_vintage.vintage_id)
   or exists(select 1 from pr_blog_entries where pr_blog_entries.fk_vintage_id = pr_video_vintage.vintage_id)
```

or

```
    SELECT  distinct vintage_id FROM `pr_video_vintage`
where pr_video_vintage.vintage_id in (select pr_video.fk_vintage_id from pr_video)
   or pr_video_vintage.vintage_id in (select pr_reports.fk_vintage_id from pr_reports)
   or pr_video_vintage.vintage_id in (select pr_reports_notes.fk_vintage_id from pr_reports_notes)
   or pr_video_vintage.vintage_id in (select pr_blog_entries.fk_vintage_id from pr_blog_entries)
```

or

```
SELECT  distinct vintage_id FROM `pr_video_vintage`
where pr_video_vintage.vintage_id in (
   select pr_video.fk_vintage_id from pr_video
   union
   select pr_reports.fk_vintage_id from pr_reports
   union
   select pr_reports_notes.fk_vintage_id from pr_reports_notes
   union
   select pr_blog_entries.fk_vintage_id from pr_blog_entries)
```

Comment: Top one seems to do the trick - the second statement also works, if the table references in the () for the last three statements are corrected.  Thanks!

Comment: For reference, (in this case at least) the second option seems marginally faster than the first, which is in turn faster than the third...

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an OUTER JOIN or LEFT/RIGHT JOIN. OUTER JOIN computes the cartesian product of all entries including entries that are not present in both tables. LEFT JOIN shows everything in the table in the left hand side of the ON statement whether or not it exists in the right hand side, and RIGHT JOIN does the opposite.

Also, INNER JOIN is the same thing as JOIN if you want to save yourself some keystrokes!

Comment: Thanks for the tip on INNER JOIN - I did try RIGHT join during my efforts, but it didn't seem to do what I needed.  Mt. Schneiders code above does what I need...

Answer (score 0):

You can run `LEFT JOIN`s, which will return a NULL Id for nonexisting links, combined with a clause to exclude those rows which have *all* links NULLed.

```
SELECT DISTINCT vintage_id FROM `pr_video_vintage`
LEFT JOIN pr_video
    ON pr_video.fk_vintage_id = pr_video_vintage.vintage_id
LEFT JOIN pr_reports
    ON pr_reports.fk_vintage_id = pr_video_vintage.vintage_id
LEFT JOIN pr_reports_notes
    ON pr_reports_notes.fk_vintage_id = pr_video_vintage.vintage_id
LEFT JOIN pr_blog_entries
    ON pr_blog_entries.fk_vintage_id = pr_video_vintage.vintage_id
WHERE
    pr_video.fk_vintage_id IS NOT NULL
    OR
    pr_reports.fk_vintage_id IS NOT NULL
    OR
    pr_reports_notes.fk_vintage_id IS NOT NULL
    OR
    pr_blog_entries.fk_vintage_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY `pr_video_vintage`.`vintage_id` ASC
```